# Dynamically create a tree graph and walk around it

Tags: java, graph-theory

I have a graph which will be fed using an external source. So far, a rough structure is something like this:

[image: TreeGraph, shown this way to fit]
. In there, the red lines represent siblings of the node, which might be dependency but not a parenthood itself. It might or might not exist.

Currently, I have this code for each node:

```
    public class TreeNode {    
        private int id;
        private int container; 
        private int status;
        private int value;  
        private boolean visited;
        private String node_name;       
        private ArrayList children = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList siblings = new ArrayList();
        private ArrayList parents = new ArrayList();

        public TreeNode()
        {
            this.id = 0;
            this.status = 0;
            this.visited = false;
            this.node_name="";
        }
        //Getters and setters below.    
        //parents/siblings/children are added through addParent(treeNode);
    }
```

Then, I have this code to set the values:

```
    public class TreeSetter {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            TreeNode A = new TreeNode();        
            TreeNode B = new TreeNode();
            TreeNode C = new TreeNode();
            TreeNode D = new TreeNode();        
            TreeNode E = new TreeNode();
            TreeNode F = new TreeNode();
            TreeNode G = new TreeNode();
            TreeNode H = new TreeNode();

            A.setId(1);
            A.setNode_name("A");
            A.setStatus(1);
            A.addParent(null);

            B.setId(2);
            B.setNode_name("B");
            B.setStatus(1);
            B.addParent(A);
            A.addChildren(B);

            C.setId(3);
            C.setNode_name("C");
            C.setStatus(1);
            C.addParent(A);
            A.addChildren(C);

            D.setId(4);
            D.setNode_name("D");
            D.setStatus(1);
            D.addParent(A);
            A.addChildren(D);

            E.setId(5);
            E.setNode_name("E");
            E.setStatus(1);
            E.addParent(B);
            E.addParent(C);
            E.addParent(D);
            B.addChildren(E);
            C.addChildren(E);
            D.addChildren(E);
            E.addSiblings(F);
            E.addSiblings(G);
            E.addSiblings(H);       

            F.setId(6);
            F.setNode_name("F");
            F.setStatus(1);
            F.addParent(B);
            F.addParent(C);
            F.addParent(D);
            B.addChildren(F);
            C.addChildren(F);
            D.addChildren(F);
            F.addSiblings(E);
            F.addSiblings(G);
            F.addSiblings(H);

            G.setId(7);
            G.setNode_name("G");
            G.setStatus(1);
            G.addParent(B);
            G.addParent(C);
            G.addParent(D);
            B.addChildren(G);
            C.addChildren(G);
            D.addChildren(G);
            G.addSiblings(E);
            G.addSiblings(F);
            G.addSiblings(H);

            H.setId(8);
            H.setNode_name("H");
            H.setStatus(1);
            H.addParent(B);
            H.addParent(C);
            H.addParent(D);
            B.addChildren(H);
            C.addChildren(H);
            D.addChildren(H);
            H.addSiblings(E);
            H.addSiblings(F);
            H.addSiblings(G);
            //Set all other nodes

            //Set all node values.  
        }    
    }
```

So, what I need is, let's say that given H, I need to know:

- What is the value from H -> I -> L (H+I+L)
- Who will be affected if H changes. H -> B,C,D -> A
- What are the dependencies of H? F, G, E.

Given this, my troubles are:

- How do I create the tree dynamically? For example, let's say that instead of 12 nodes, you have 1000. Using my code, I will need a lot of lines just to set the values and relations because I am creating every single object by hand. Should I use reflection, factory paradigm to create the 1000 objects?
- How do I walk the tree? For example, given D, move D->H->I->L (and so on).
  I know recursion would be the easiest and cleanest way to do it, but I don't know how to implement it :(

Comment: The siblings form three groups by red-linking, and for each groups G1, G2, all the items of G1 are black-linked to all the items of G2. I think that it's superfluous to addParent/Children/Siblings explicitly. I'd rather have a list for each group.

Comment: @Ignis So basically what you're saying is that instead of linking every single object by level, I should create a new list every time that a new level occurrs?

Comment: Yes, it would save you lots of lines to write (and save your program a O(n^2) computation).

Comment: You can find a tutorial on recursion here. http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch18-recurex/index.html

Comment: ... Keep in mind that recursion could kill your stack if there are too many levels. And that any recursive algorithm can be rewritten in iterative form.

Comment: @ignis That's the trouble I always have had with recursion: I always ended up writing iteratives when trying to set the stop condition.

Comment: @StrayChild01 Are there values associated to each edge in the graph? I'm a bit confused by your image. What does the red/black lines represent?

Comment: @ahenderson Yes, there are values on each node. The black lines mean that a node is has a relationship with another node, for example:

A is parent of B, C and D. A, B, C are parents of E, F, G, H.

So, if they are processes, let's say that G fails. It is going to impact J, I, K (sons) and L (grandson). It might impact E, F, H, but we don't need to walk all the tree down as well for those. In the real case scenario some relations might or not exist. I used the redlines to emphasize the siblings.

Comment: @StrayChild01 This makes much more sense to me as a family tree. Is that what it is?

Comment: @aHenderson Yes, it is. Starting with A and the latest children is L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I create the tree dynamically:**

```
public class Tree {

    private class Node {
        public int value;
        public List<Node> = new children ArrayList<Node>();
        public List<Node> = new parents ArrayList<Node>();
        public static final INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        public void addChild(Node n) {
            children.add(n);
        }

        public void addParent(Node n) {
            parents.add(n);
        }

        public int getValue() {return value;}

        //What is the value from H -> I -> L (H+I+L):
        int getValueToNode(Node Destination, HashSet<Node> s) {
           int minValue = INFINITY;
           int value = 0;

           if(s.contains(this)) return INFINITY; //we already checked this
           s.add(this);
           if(this.equals(Destination)) return Destination.value();

           for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
               Node c = children.get(i);
               int value = c.getValueToNode(Destination);
               if (value != Integer.MAX_VALUE && value < minValue) {
                   minValue = value + this.getValue();
               }
           }

           for(int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++) {
               Node p = parents.get(i);
               value = p.getValueToNode(Destination);
               if (value != Integer.MAX_VALUE && value < minValue) {
                   minValue = value + this.getValue();
               }
           }
           return minValue;
        }

        //Who will be affected if H changes. H -> B,C,D -> A
        public int getDependency(ArrayList<Node> affected) {
          for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
               Node c = children.get(i);
               affected.add(c);
           }

           for(int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++) {
               Node p = parents.get(i);
               affected.add(p);
           }
        }

        //What are the dependencies of H? F, G, E.
        List<Node> getDependency() {
           List<Node> dependency = new ArrayList<Node>();
           for(int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++) {
               Node p = parents.get(i);
               for(int j= 0 ; j < p.children.size(); j++) {
                   Node c = p.children.get(i);
                   if(!c.equals(this)) dependency.add(c);
               }
           }
           return dependency;
        }
    }

    //data here.
    private Map<String, Node> mapping = new HashMap<String, Node>();

    public connectParentToChild(String parent, String child) {
        Node p = getNode(parent);
        Node c = getNode(child);
        p.addChild(c);
        c.addParent(p);
    }

    public int getValue(String first, String second) {
        a = getNode(first);
        b = getNode(second);
        HashSet<Node> s = new HashSet<Node>();
        return a.getValueToNode(b, s);
    }

    private Node getNode(String s) {
        if(!mapping.containsKey(s)) {
           mapping.put(s, new Node(...));
        }
        return mapping.get(s);
    }

    //members here.
}
```

This is a simple way to dynamically add nodes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree t;
    t.connectParentToChild("A", "D");
    t.connectParentToChild("A", "B");
    t.connectParentToChild("A", "C");
    t.connectParentToChild("B", "C");
    t.connectParentToChild("B", "H");
    t.connectParentToChild("B", "F");
    t.connectParentToChild("B", "E");
    //Set all other nodes
    t.getValue("H", "L");
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, it is very clear. I have a question, though: If I expose the node with something like `getNodeByS(String s){ return this.mapping.get(s); }` so I can set the values for each node, I'll be searching a lot of times, right?

Comment: Nevermind, I put the inner Node class outside, created an overcharged constructor and call it.

Comment: @StrayChild01 I made updates based on what I understand. I just have one question what is a dependencies of H mean?

Comment: Dependencies are the siblings. About walking the tree, I have something like this: `
public Node walkTree(Map<Integer, Node> tree, String s)
{
 Node currentNode = new Node(); 
 currentNode = tree.get(s);
 if (currentNode.connections.size() <= 1)
 {   
  return currentNode.connections.get(0);
 }
 else
 {      
  tempNode = currentNode.connections.get(0);
  currentNode.connections.remove(0);
  return walkTree(tree, currentNode.get);
 }
}
`
But it doesn't work :(

Comment: @StrayChild01 I updated it to include getDependency. What does it mean to walk the tree? I don't understand from the code you posted above.

Comment: It was an attempt to create what you did on getValueToNode. I am sure you're going to hate me, but I got a StackOverflowError on getValueToNode when calling t.getValue("H","L");

Comment: StrayChild01 Good catch, i didn't account for the cycles in the graph. I should warn you this code is not fully tested so use it only as a guide. I'll update it to handle the cycles and remove the stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't be modest: The code needed very slight modifications to make it fully functional. That's why I knew about the stack overflow.

Comment: @StrayChild01 getValueToNode(...) will get you a value to a node but it may not get you the smallest value. Is that okay?

Comment: Actually what I need is the max value and the sum. For example `H(1) -> I(9) -> L(4) get (1+9+4) and (9)`. But I think if I make max value global and save it should do the trick, right?

Comment: @StrayChild01 No, the issue is to get from H to L. From what I understand the you can take the path H->B->A->C->E->K->L or any other valid path. Are there any restriction like you can only check parent to children?

Comment: Yes. For example: H -> L. You would need to check K,I,J and L. You don't care about H siblings (red lines), H parents (B,C,D) or H ancestors (A). For the weight, you only check the children. It might not be the lowest value in the tree, but it is in the subtree.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printWholeNode(Node root) {
    if (root.getChildren().size() == 0) {
        if (root.visited == false) {
            System.out.println(root.name);
            root.visited = true;
        }
        return ;
    } else {
        System.out.println(root.name);
        root.visited = true;
        for (Node childNode : root.getChildren()) {
            printWholeNode(childNode);
        }
    }
}
```